# update only product name and sub product name do not update product image in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on simple product page using *php mysql*. It has three field *product_name*, *sub_product_name* and *product_image*, My question is how to update only *product_name* and keep *sub_product_name* and *product_image* as it is.
If anyone know how to do this, it would be great, Many thanks in advance. :)

i'm using this code for update.

```
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('product_db');
error_reporting(0); 

$myid = $_GET['id'];


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
  $errors= array();
  $file_name = $_FILES['product_image']['name'];
  $file_size = $_FILES['product_image']['size'];
  $file_tmp = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type = $_FILES['product_image']['type'];
  $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['product_image']['name'])));

  $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

  if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
     $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
  }

  if($file_size > 2097152) {
     $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
  }

  if(empty($errors)==true) 
  {
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"../icon/".$file_name);


        $product_name=$_POST['product_name'];
        $sub_product_name = $_POST['sub_product_name'];
        $product_image="icon/" . $_FILES["product_image"]["name"];


        $update = "update product_table set product_name = '$product_name', sub_product_name = '$sub_product_name', product_image = '$product_image' where id= '$myid'";


        if (mysql_query($update))
            {
                    $msg = "Product update successfully!";
            }
                else
            {
            echo "error";
            }

    }
```

Comment: Can you show us your code .what your are doing

Comment: Google SQL Update Statement

Comment: @KumarPraveen please check my code, Thank you!

Comment: in your query why are you updating subproduct_name

Comment: update product_table set product_name = '$product_name', product_image = '$product_image' where id= '$myid'"

Comment: leave it for now suppose i don't update product_image only want to update product_name and keep sub_product_name and product_image as it is in database. so how do it??

Comment: Under what condition would you actually want to update `sub_product_name` and what condition for `product_image`?

Comment: Your update statement updates all 3 fields.  Just update only one, the other values in the line will not change.  Ex: `UPDATE product_table SET product_name = 'somevalue' WHERE id = '$myid'`.  This will change only the product_name column value in the line for id == $myid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very too simple thing you need to do is, modify your update sql query to this:

```
    $update = "update product_table set product_name = '$product_name' where id= '$myid'";
```

Always, include those fields only in the update query which you want to update.

Comment: Thanks @Hetal Chauhan.......its work now i used if condition for it......

`if($product_image == "")
{
$update = "update product_table set product_name = '$product_name', sub_product_name = '$sub_product_name' where id= '$myid'";
}
else
{
$update = "update product_table set product_name = '$product_name', sub_product_name = '$sub_product_name', product_image = '$product_image' where id= '$myid'"; `